# CDT 9 removes support for different ASTCompletionNode proposals

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

The changes introduced in CDT 9* ([diff link](https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/blob/master/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/text/contentassist/DOMCompletionProposalComputer.java#L165)) removes support for `ASTCompletionNode`'s of different type than `org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.ASTCompletionNode`.

If a plugin adds a contribution and inserts completion proposals which implement a different `IASTCompletionNode`, (e.g. the `ASTCompletionNode` from the `org.eclipse.cdt.core.lrparser`, the following exception is thrown on `Ctrl + Space`:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.lrparser.action.ASTCompletionNode cannot be cast to org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.ASTCompletionNode
    at` `org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.text.contentassist.DOMCompletionProposalComputer.computeCompletionProposals(DOMCompletionProposalComputer.java:165)`

What workarround do I have in this situation?

Comment: In my opinion the cast is not required. The list of `ASTName`'s could have been taken directly from the `IASTCompletionNode completionNode` parameter: `completionNade.getNames()`.

Comment: Hi Garry, this is a perfectly on topic question for posting on CDT's own mailing list where the CDT devs are. Please join and post your question there. https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cdt-dev
(BTW your diff link does not link to a diff, but the current HEAD of that file, I assume the link you meant was https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/commit/301de3d40ea15dfc84a90c227db62514cd2dc578#diff-19331ecebde5f615f5314093bd61e95dR165 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [on the mailing list](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cdt-dev/msg33310.html), the cast is unnecessary, and has been removed.